React native expo build is showing unknown error while generating apk for Android. V49
The project was working fine months ago, coming back to generate apk for Android and it's showing unknown error.
Build failed: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Go to expo.dev, select project and under builds, find this failing build. Then in that failed build, open "Run gradlew" process logs and look for errors there

@iamjansons I used the approach you outlined and saw the issue was caused by one of my dependacies. I removed the dependency which was even of no use to my project. It has worked perfectly. Thanks

Great ;) Good luck with your project. posted same comment as answer, so you can close this question

Go to expo.dev, select project and under builds, find this failing build. Then in that failed build, open "Run gradlew" process logs and look for errors there
